# How to allow integer receive null in combox.value?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

```
   Private Sub SubmitButton1_Click()
 Dim month As Integer
 Dim fromm As Integer
 Dim too As Integer


month = monthComboBox.Value
fromm = fromComboBox.Value
too = toComboBox.Value
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''
'''''''''''''


Dim sSQLQry As String
Dim ReturnArray

Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String



DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName



sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

Conn.Open sconnect

If (IsNull(fromComboBox.Value)) And (IsNull(toComboBox.Value)) = True Then
      sSQLSting = "SELECT  officer  From  [big$]  where officer is not null and officer <> '' and officer <> ' ' and Month between " & fromm & " and " & too & " group by officer "
  Set rs = Conn.Execute(sSQLSting)
  Else
  sSQLSting = "SELECT  officer  From  [big$]  where officer is not null and officer <> '' and officer <> ' ' and Month= " & month & " group by officer " ' 


    Set rs = Conn.Execute(sSQLSting)
    End If
```

[enter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkeUn.png) 
**Case:**
3 combobox here .The user should select either "by month" or " by month period".These 3 combobox option inside are all same .additem 1 .additem 2 .additem 3  ... .additem 12

I use `If (IsNull(fromComboBox.Value)) And (IsNull(toComboBox.Value)) = True Then A SQL A else-SQL-B`

Now , it shows a datatype mismatch error on `month = monthComboBox.Value
fromm = fromComboBox.Value
too = toComboBox.Value`

In my opinion ,as the user should input "by month" or "by month period" , one combobox.value should be "" (string datatype) . Hence , it occurs datatype mismatch .(the variable store combobox.value is in integer)

How to solve ?
Btw ,`If (IsNull(fromComboBox.Value)) And (IsNull(toComboBox.Value)) = True Then A SQL A else-SQL-B` ,it seems that this condition does not fully work . Any idea ?

## Update

**1)i use these code to solve null can't pass integer problem .Dunno it works or not .**

```
 Dim month As Integer
     Dim fromm As Integer
     Dim too As Integer

If IsNumeric(monthComboBox.Value) Then
month = monthComboBox.Value
Else
month = 0
End If
''''
If IsNumeric(fromComboBox.Value) Then
fromm = fromComboBox.Value
Else
fromm = 0
End If
'''''
If IsNumeric(toComboBox.Value) Then
too = toComboBox.Value
Else
too = 0
End If
```

**2) The if condition is not working .The result :"Else statement " work for monthcombobox ; "Then statement no effect . In other words , only "by month combobox works .There is no output for "by month period"**

```
If ((IsEmpty(fromComboBox.Value) Or IsNull(fromComboBox.Value)) = True And (IsEmpty(toComboBox.Value)) Or IsNull(toComboBox.Value)) = True Then 
  sSQLSting = "SELECT  officer  From  [big$]  where officer is not null and officer <> '' and officer <> ' ' and Month between " & fromm & " and " & too & " group by officer "
  Set rs = Conn.Execute(sSQLSting)
  Else
  sSQLSting = "SELECT  officer  From  [big$]  where officer is not null and officer <> '' and officer <> ' ' and Month= " & month & " group by officer " ' 


    Set rs = Conn.Execute(sSQLSting)
    End If
```

Comment: what is month = monthComboBox.Value is returning ?

Comment: @Manjuboyz it return ""

Comment: it is returning empty, is it ok if you change it to string after you getting the value, like : fromComboBox.Value.ToString().

Comment: @Manjuboyz i now change the datatype to string to hold .combobox.value . it is okay .But the problem is that it causes problem when inserting the variable into the SQL statement  .Now it become `Month= `` . 'month='? should be in numeric format so that the SQL works

Comment: You can cast string to int, if not put a check if value.toString() is returning empty, assign integer value '0' so that it will have integer value and pass that to sql. I guess it will work for you.

Comment: @Manjuboyz i have made update showing my progress . mostly ,not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to check for a `ComboBox` object value selection use its `ListIndex` property

furthermore your logic needs enhancements to let you catch and use any "valid" user choice and reject any invalid one

finally your code has some undeclared and/or unused variables: you'd better use `Option Explicit` at the very top of your module and force you to declare all variables: at the cost of this little extra work you'll gain much more control over your code and make subsequent debugging and maintenance work much faster

for all what above you code use the following code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SubmitButton1_Click()

Dim month As Integer
Dim fromm As Integer
Dim too As Integer
Dim sSQLString As String

With Me
    Select Case True
        Case .monthComboBox.ListIndex <> -1 '<--| a valid "by month" choice has been made, then use it to build consequent SQL string
            month = monthComboBox.value
            sSQLString = "SELECT  officer  From  [big$]  where officer is not null and officer <> '' and officer <> ' ' and Month= " & month & " group by officer "

        Case .fromComboBox.ListIndex <> -1 And .toComboBox.ListIndex <> -1 '<--| a valid "by month period" choice has been made, then use it to build consequent SQL string
            fromm = fromComboBox.value
            too = toComboBox.value
            sSQLString = "SELECT  officer  From  [big$]  where officer is not null and officer <> '' and officer <> ' ' and Month between " & fromm & " and " & too & " group by officer "

        Case Else '<--| no vaild "month" choice hase been made, then inform the user about it
            MsgBox "invalid months data choice!", vbInformation + vbExclamation
    End Select
End With

If sSQLString = "" Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if no SQL string has been initilalized

Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"
Conn.Open sconnect
Set rs = Conn.Execute(sSQLString)

'Dim sSQLQry As String '<--| are you actually using them?
'Dim ReturnArray '<--| are you actually using them?


End Sub
```